# how to get the list items in sharepoint 2013 using c#

Tags: sharepoint-addin, csom

I have tried this code but it is not working..

```
 SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
 SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Vehicle");
 SPListItemCollection coll = list.GetItems();
 foreach (SPItem item in coll)
 {
     string vehId = (item.ID).ToString();
     Label1.Text = (string)item["AssignDriver"];
 }
```

Comment: what error are you getting with this code?this code has no error it should work.if you are getting any permission related issue then execute your code inside   SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
      {});

Answer (score 0):

You use below CSOM code to fetch list items from the Sharepoint

```
Web oWebsite = spctx.Web;

List _lst = oWebsite.Lists.GetByTitle("List Name");
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection _lstCol = _lst.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());

spctx.Load(_lst);
spctx.Load(_lstCol);
spctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem _item in _lstCol)
{
    string ID = _item.FieldValues["ID"].ToString();
    string Title = _item.FieldValues["Title"].ToString();
}
```

For Server side code you use below

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Vehicle");
SPListItemCollection coll = list.Items;
foreach (SPListItem item in coll)
{
 string vehId = (item.ID).ToString();
 Label1.Text = (string)item["AssignDriver"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Vehicle");
```

with

```
SPList list = web.Lists["Vehicle"];
```

and it will work just fine!

Answer (score -1):

Try this It will help you

```
    using (var site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var campaignList = web.Lists["Vehicle"];

                        var spQuery = new SPQuery
                        {
                            Query = "<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name=Title' /></IsNotNull></Where>"
                        };
                        var Items = campaignList.GetItems(spQuery);
                        if (Items != null && Items.Count > 0)
                        {
                        string Title = item["Title"].ToString() !=null && item["Title"].ToString()!=string.Empty?item["Title"].ToString():string.Empty;
                        string vehId = item["ID"].ToString();
                        }
                   }
                   catch(Exception ex)
                   {
                   } 
               }
           }
```

Please Change Query As per your requirement